# git - не удаляются файлы, которые являются неактуальными в папке bin/debug

Tags: c#, git

Всем привет!
Имеется проблема, при билде проекта автоматически собирается папка ***bin/debug***
проблема следующая: если я удаляю из основной папки какой - либо неактуальный файл, который впоследствии попадет в папку **debug** (в моем случае это json, в которых у нас хранятся ряд определенных конфигураций для проекта - их много)
и запушу это изменение через гит у себя локально,
 то почему этот файл не удаляется на основной удаленной машине с этим проектом,
 при следующем выкачивании моих изменений из git и последующей сборкой проекта, приходится их удалять вручную, подскажите, какой может быть выход, спасибо.

**git pull** происходит без ошибок, т.е он просто игнорирует неактуальные файлы, которые по идее должны при сборке удалиться.

Comment: а что такое "неактуальные файлы"? и каким образом удаленный файл после сборки появляется в папке deb**a**g?

Comment: Служебные папки типа bin и debug никоим образом не должны попадать в git. Точка. Вы что-то делаете не так. Если это файлы конфигурации - то почему они лежат в bin/debug? Также если это файлы конфигурации - то их складировать в репозиторий не нужно, в репозитории должен храниться эталлонный файл допустим myjsonsetup.json.sample и на каждой машине каждый разработчик должен создать локальный файл  myjsonsetup.json с индивидуальными настройками под свою конкретную машину. И  myjsonsetup.json должен игнорироваться git'ом

Comment: Папки bin и obj должны быть внесены в .gitignore, их не должно быть в репозитории вообще.

Comment: что то мне подсказывает, что эти файлы создаются в результате запуска скомпилированного бинарника